# Wireless portable peripheral hub instead of wireless portable peripherals?

Tags: usb, usb-hub, peripherals, portable-harddrive

I'm having difficulty finding such a device, probably because I don't really have the right search term for them or they don't exist.

I have tried:

- Wireless usb hub,
- Bluetooth usb hub,
- Portable usb hub,
- Wireless peripheral hub

No luck finding what I am looking for

What I'm looking for is a on-the-train workstation solution to all of my boredom problems. I spend a lot of time commuting using public transit. That's a lot of unproductive sitting-time. I want to make more use of that time.

Problem, is I can only take my backpack with me, I can't take my desk.

So, what I'm searching for is a (hopefully plug-n-play) device that allows me to plug in flashdrives, external HDDs, card readers, and other miscellaneous external devices (like TI-84 graphing calculators, smart phones, microcomputers, web cameras, audio equipment, bla, bla, bla) cordlessly, with a ***built-in power supply*** (As much as I'd like buses, uber cars, and trains to have outlets, they don't)

I'm thinking it would use wireless networking, and not bluetooth, because I don't think bluetooth can handle a tremendous load.

Answer (score 0):

These things do exist in theory - for example  https://m.alibaba.com/product/60020735464/Protable-1000M-hub-2-0-print.html?spm=a2706.7843667.1998817009.6.AQcVLj#show_specifications- but they seem to overwhelmingly be unpolished junk. You might get lucky though.   As far as powering them, as this uses 5v, 2 amps, you could use a USB power bank - and 3d print a case if necessary.

Half a step up might be http://www.silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/device-networking/usb-parallel-connectivity/ds-600/ - but as it requires 12 volts you would need a more sophisticated power bank. They do exist (I have one) but are clunkier, bigger and harder to find. Look at stores that sell car accessories - these things are sometimes sold as jump starters.

Lastly I found https://www.eltima.com/usb-over-wifi/ but It's short on price and specs.

Comment: Using the search term ["**portable** device server"](https://www.google.com/search?q=portable+device+server&rlz=1C1NHXL_enUS752US752&oq=portable+device+server&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.9325j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), I found [this nifty device by Sony](https://www.amazon.com/Sony-Portable-Wireless-Server-WGC10/dp/B00CZ7510K)

Comment: Using the search term ["portable wireless server"](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=portable+wireless+server&oq=&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.35i39k1l6.0.0.0.4279.2.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..1.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..1.1.117.6...118.87LhIeG5-fc) I found this [other nifty device by Sony](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7IWclw1FYQ)

Comment: I'm thinking I make something similar using a microcomputer like a raspberry pi attached to "dock" or peripheral hub